# Divide X-axis of a graph in weeks in windows form visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

i want to show data of an year(2013-14) on my graph and want to break my x-axis in weeks (around 52 columns) in windows form visual studio 2010. Please tell me how to set it.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: yes, i have solved it already but thanks for your reply TaW

Answer (score 0):

The code below

- fills a Chart Series with one point per day for a given year
- sets the Y-values to random test value
- will **either:**

  - show one date every 7 days
  - **or** show the week number for the frist day of each week

Please note: The week number can be calculated in various ways, depending on the culture info on your machine. If you need, you can always set the values of `CalendarWeekRule` and `FirstDayOfWeek` to the ones you actually want.

---

```
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
using System.Globalization;

private void setChart(int Year)
{

    bool showAsDate = true;
    var s = new Series(year.ToString() );
    s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
    var d = new DateTime(year, 01, 01);
    int weekday = (int)d.DayOfWeek;
    int maxDays = new DateTime(year, 12, 31).DayOfYear;

    Random R = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < maxDays ; i++)
    {
        s.Points.AddXY(d.AddDays(i), R.Next(100) - 50);
    }

    chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();
    chart1.Series.Clear();
    chart1.Series.Add(s);

    if (showAsDate )
    {
        chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "MM-dd";
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 7;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffset = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        DateTimeFormatInfo dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
        Calendar cal = dfi.Calendar;
        for (int i = 0; i < maxDays ; i++)
        {
           chart1.Series[0].Points[i].AxisLabel = 
                  cal.GetWeekOfYear(d.AddDays(i), 
                  dfi.CalendarWeekRule, dfi.FirstDayOfWeek).ToString();
           chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffset = 2 - weekday;
        }
    }
```